# SMW+ installation in MAMP

Tags: mediawiki, mamp, semantics

I'm trying to instal SMW+ on MAMP on top of an existing Semantic Mediawiki (that installation went fine).

First problem: in [Step 3 of the official SMW+ installation guide](http://www.smwplus.net/index.php/Help:Installing_SMW+_1.7.0_manually_on_top_of_MediaWiki), the WYSIWYG editor doesn't have a link, and the SMWHalo extension locks up my wiki.

So, in Step 6, I've had to comment out    # include_once('extensions/SMWHalo/includes/SMW_Initialize.php'); enableSMWHalo(); and require_once("$IP/extensions/WYSIWYG/WYSIWYG.php");

I figured it was related to SMWHalo on both counts. So, I hop over to the [Halo Extension installation guide](http://smwplus.net/index.php/Help:Installing_Halo_extension_1.7.0), which leads me to the Wiki Admin Tool installation guide (no link because I'm a noob), which is where I get stuck. I can't get smwadmin to become executable to save my life chmod +x smwadmin.sh returns nothing, and using smwadmin after that gives me "-bash: smwadmin: command not found"

And there, I'm stuck. My wiki still works just fine with those three lines commented out, but I obviously lose SMW+ functionality.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Just switch to regular SMW and use the Semantic Bundle to get a jumpstart.  I'm afraid the SMW+ project, for all intents and purposes, is now dead :(